# VideoJS Flash Fallback Not Working When Dynamically Changing Source

Tags: html, flash, firefox, video.js

I'm having issues with my videos not being played back in firefox.  I'm attempting to dynamically update one `video` element's source to play multiple videos without re-creating the element every time my function is called.

E.g., first click makes the `video` source = video1.mp4, next click maintains that `video` player, but changes the source = video2.mp4 without recreating the element.

My reason for doing this is to only have to use one filetype for all browsers. I realize I could just make another `source` tag under the `video` element and give it a MIME type of `video/ogg` and it would work with HTML5 in firefox, but I want to have a universal format to take the burden off my users.

I can get this to work perfectly fine in chrome, but when changing to firefox the flash player only plays the first video source then
for some reason becomes undefined.

Firstly, I created a video element inside a lightbox. The lightbox is opened through a function which is called onclick of an anchor tag. When the lightbox is opened, I initialize a videojs player of the video, then set its source to the URL passed into the function. I then load the player, and play it. This works perfectly fine in chrome with HTML5, but in firefox the flash fallback works once then breaks.

I was reading about the problem and thought my problem might be the fact that flash converts the  `video` element into a flash `object`, then when I try to reference the video with the same ID again, it isn't found because it doesn't exist as a `video` element anymore.

#### Here is a code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7WTrh/12/

I tested in chrome, and it works, but firefox does not.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When you're changing the source, you need to make sure you're passing the mime type as well, so video.js knows what tech it needs.

```
myPlayer.src({ src: "vid.mp4", type: "video/mp4" });
```

Comment: I edited the fiddle, but now firefox says invalid URI, while chrome plays the first video fine. I can navigate straight to the first URI, but the video element won't support it. http://jsfiddle.net/7WTrh/14/